# 'Class' is ambiguous

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, ambiguous

I am trying to build my solution and am getting a "'VirtualMarchRegistrationDAL' is ambiguous" error. I have yet to find anything helpful on any forums. Here is the code that is being used:

```
Private Function submitRegistration() As Boolean
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim lastName As String
    Dim emailAddress As String
    Dim zip As String


    firstName = firstNameTxt.Text
    lastName = lastNameTxt.Text
    emailAddress = emailTxt.Text
    zip = zipTxt.Text

    Return VirtualMarchRegistrationDAL.addRegistration(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, zip)

End Function
```

The error is occurring on the return statement. The DAL that it is referring to is located in the App_Code folder.

Thanks for your help,
2Rhino53

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have multiple accessible items with the name of `VirtualMarchRegistrationDAL`. They are not necessary two classes. They might be a class and a namespace .. You have to check it out.

Try to use the fully qualified name of the class. Like the following:

```
NameSpaceName.VirtualMarchRegistrationDAL. ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 copies of the class in your project, perhaps in different namespaces?  If both namespaces are imported, you would need to fully qualify any reference.